# TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'autorise

Tags: python, python-3.x, webbrowser

Всем привет.Для отображения веб-страниц я использую webbrowser(встроенный в python модуль).
Url написал правильно,new=1.Почему он не принимает аргумент autorise(значение True)?

Comment: Потому что это слово пишется иначе.

Comment: И если True, то не надо указывать специально, оно такое по умолчанию.